# Entity being tracked despite AsNoTracking

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have an object, Client, with a navigation property that is a list of Order objects. Whenever I retrieve a Client object, I include the list of Orders, with AsNoTracking().

```
public new IQueryable<Client> FindByConditionNoTracking(Expression<Func<Client, bool>> expression)
{
    return this.ClientContext.Set<Client>().Include(s => s.Orders)
               .Where(expression).AsNoTracking();
}
```

In my UpdateClient repository method, I take in a Client object. I then attempt to retrieve that original client from the database (using Include to get the child Orders), map the Client param to the original, and save to the database. Over here, I do not use AsNoTracking, because I specifically want the changes to be tracked.

```
public new void Update(Client client)
    {

        var id = client.ClientId;
        var original = this.ClientContext.Clients.Include(s => s.Orders).Where(s => s.ClientId == id)
                        .FirstOrDefault<Client>();
        original = _mapper.Map(client, original);
        this.ClientContext.Update(original);
    }
```

The error I am getting is that an instance of Order with the same key value is already being tracked. A few problems with that:

1. Wherever the Client and the child Orders are retrieved for the purposes of display I use AsNoTracking.
2. The only place where I retrieve without AsNoTracking is where I get the original within this very method.
3. The bug isn't with the parent property. If I was improperly retrieving the Client elsewhere, wouldn't I have this error with the Client id itself? But the error seems to be only with the navigation property.

All insight is appreciated!

Comment: `map the Client param to the original` - Show the code which do this.

Comment: Added in the code - I'm using automapper.

Comment: If you have to map, why use `AsNoTracking()` in the first place? That's the actual problem.

Comment: Can you explain? What is the actual problem?

Comment: I'm using AsNoTracking because the FindByCondition is not always used for editing; it is most frequently used just for display.

Comment: Your mapper might be creating new objects of order instead of mapping `client.order`'s properties to `original.order`'s properties.

Comment: @mker *don't* use that method if you intend to edit the object. By using the wrong method you end up making the same (SQL) calls twice

Comment: Ah Mat J that's an interesting idea. I have to look into how automapper implements collection mapping. Thank you.

Comment: Mat J you are definitely on to something; telling automapper to ignore mapping that property does solve the problem. What's strange is that there are other navigation properties (i.e. PhoneNumbers) of Client that are mapped with automapper, without a problem. I'm not sure why that would be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this: Automapper, when mapping collections, apparently recreates the entire collection. I solved the above issue by using Automapper.Collections in my mapping configuration. Thanks to Mat J for the tip!